# Categorized dictionary of the English language

Tags: dictionaries, category, taxonomy

What dictionaries are there available which offer some kind of classification of words into different categories? I am looking for a free alternative to WordStat.

I would like to use the categorization of the dictionary as some kind of map to be able to get some sense of the "location" of a word in respect to other words in any kind of a coherent distribution, such as categorization.

Comment: Yep, a thesaurus along the style of Roget's is probably the closest to what you want.  (Do be warned that there are thesauri that are "dictionary style" which are less well organized for your apparent requirements.)

Comment: [Roger Prebble](http://bnb.data.bl.uk/doc/person/PrebbleRoger) published some very useful (to crossword enthusiasts! :) "categorised" word lists through Chambers a few years back. My copies are getting a bit dog-eared by now, but I'm constantly surprised by how useful his particular choice of categories turns out to be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Answer (score 1):

> **Roget's Thesaurus**, 6th Edition Barbara Ann Kipfer, ‎Robert L. Chapman
>   - 2003
>
> Provides more than 230,000 synonyms, antonyms, and related words in
>   more than a thousand different **categories**.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/Roget-Alpha-Index.html